# Artifactory corrupts nodejs modules index file; .npm/<module>/package.json

Tags: node.js, artifactory

Artifactory creates a .npm directory in the artifact cache that holds indexes for node modules; package.json. This file can become corrupt resulting in a 500 error when pulling artifacts for that module. The only solution right now, is to delete the package.json and let it recreate it. This is a manual process requiring an admin to go in and cleanup and disrupts our CI/CD processes. Has somebody come up with a plugin or restful api call that can clean this up, or better yet, a fix so the package.json isn't corrupted in the first place. I only see maven reindexing in the api doc and don't see any plugins that do this in Github.com. This occurs at random for a wide variety of modules. We're using Artifactory 5.4.4.

Comment: Corrupt is probably too strong a word. I can't verify the file is actually corrupt. My assumption is that it's corrupt because it's supposed to be an index to the versions of the module, which I can't get to load or list when this event is occurring.

Comment: They did have an issue resolved in 5.4.6 https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory5.4.6 related to NPM. I've upgraded so we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

4 days after upgrading from 5.4.4 to 5.4.6, we have not seen the NPM corruption. I'm going to call this one a bug in Artifactory which they have now resolved.

Release Notes:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory5.4.6

> Fixed an issue in which when resolving a package from an npm
>   repository, Artifactory would throw a deserialize error to the log
>   file if one of the package's dependencies in the corresponding
>   package.json file was declared using the following
>   format:“” : { “version” : “” }.